# Ruby on Rails - Selected values are not working as expected in multiple: true (simple_form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, multiple-select

In my form, I have an `f.select` with `multiple: true`, but `select` doesn't work if it's not *hardcoded* in.

*This is my form in `new` view:*

```
= f.select :os, get_uniq_objects(:os), {}, {multiple: true }
```

*My helper*

```
def get_uniq_objects(obj)
  somethings.pluck(obj).uniq
end
```

*My controller*

```
def campaign_params
      params.require(:something).permit(os:[])
end
```

In `new` view, when OSs are selected, the result would saved as `['Linux', 'Windows']` so in my `edit` view I do as below **but** nothing gets selected:

```
= f.select :os, options_for_select(get_uniq_objects(:os), @something.os), {}, { multiple: true}
```

**BUT** if I *hardcode* them as below, everything works fine. I've even double checked what `@something.os` is by adding it to my view and its exactly like the *hardcoded* code.

```
= f.select :os, options_for_select(get_uniq_objects(:os), ['Linux', 'Windows']), {}, { multiple: true}
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a closer look into what value `f.select` got, helped me this solve this issue.

Value that was pass to it was as follow:

```
["Linux", "Windows"]
```

But for some reason, `f.select` got this array (with backslashes):

```
[\"Linux\", \"Windows\"]
```

This is my solution. In my model I did a `gsub` to change the saving values to string from an array:

```
before_save do
  self.os_name.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/, "") if attribute_present?("os_name")
end
```

so `["Linux", "Windows"]`, would become `Linux, Windows`

and I changed my `f.select` to following:

```
= f.select :os, options_for_select(get_uniq_objects(:os), @something.os.split(/\W+/)), {}, { multiple: true}
```

I did `.split(/\W+/)` to change the string to an array that `f.select` would *accept*.